# Need to apply jquery switch class to a target page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a one page website with slides that load in the different content. These are controlled by the navigation which has some switchclass jquery added to the links so each link you click switches the class of the body and therefore a different slide loads.

The problem I have is that from the blog when you open a post in full there is no way of displaying that post within the same page as the rest of the site. The CMS I'm using (Business Catalyst) opens the post in a new page which I have styled up to look like the rest of the site.

So my problem is that now the nav links on that page need to work their switchclass jquery magic on the target page when going back to the index page....

This is the jquery that is currently running the links..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".home a").click(function(){
    $("body").switchClass("default about training charities coaching blog contact", "home", 500, "swing");
});
});
```

any help greatly appreciated.